# Disclosure Indicator disappears?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I have a `UITableView` which is using custom `UITableViewCell`s to display some information. I'd like to add a `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` to the cells.

Every method that I try successfully adds the chevron, but once the table view scrolls down, they disappear. I'm doing the standard `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method, and when I dump out the references to the cells, it's re-using them properly. All of the other data displays fine, it's only the chevrons that disappear.

Things I've tried:

1. `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];`
2. `[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];`
3. `accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:`

Anyone ever have this happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could happen because you are setting your accessory type outside of the cached cell test:

```
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"UIDocumentationCell";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        [cell setText:mytext];
```

The better way, IMHO is like this:

```
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"UIDocumentationCell";
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
        [cell setText:mytext];
```

Cocoa Touch doesn't seem to want to modify the cached instance of the cell ( subviews ) setting the disclosure indicator in the cell set method results in the indicator being cached, and redrawn once the cell appears again.

Comment: As it turns out, this was not my problem, though I appreciate the best practice. Turns out I had some code that looped through the subviews, removing them. This also happened to remove the indicator, and I was only re-adding the labels.